# JWPlayer vs VideoJS | 500 Mbps = 1k users vs 300 users

Tags: jwplayer, video.js, bandwidth

Recently I switched VideoJS from JWPlayer due to high pricing. But the thing is, I was able to maintain 1000 concurrent users easily with 500 mpbs. But after switching to videoJS, I can't even pass 350 concurrent user due to bandwidth limitations.

What could be the issue? What should I check? I have checked videoJS plugins such as `http-streaming, adaptive streaming` but I couldn't get any result.

Any suggestion/help really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.